# widgets disappear after updating app, using library

Tags: android, android-widget

I have 2 versions of an app, free and paid, but have been maintaining the code separately. I've finally moved the code into a library referenced by both to make maintaining the code easier.

I found that changing the `AppwidgetProvider` caused the launcher to delete any existing widgets, so I moved those classes back out of the library to keep the provider the same so users don't have to recreate their widgets. The launcher no longer deletes the widgets, but instead, they simply don't appear after updating.

If I call `AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds` for the componentname, as it's always been, the appwidgetid is still there. The appwidgetprovider and service still get called to update the widget, and `/data/system/appwidgets.xml` still shows the widget, but the launcher never displays it.

It's not that it's invisible, as long pressing in the widget location brings up the wallpaper chooser. I can create new widgets just fine, but I don't want to frustrate users by asking them to recreate their widgets. The logs don't show any errors thrown by the launcher or `AppwidgetService`.

Any ideas why the widget stops rendering after updating? It's somehow related to moving most of the code into a separate library. Thanks!

Edit: I'm testing on an emulator, api level 15, stock launcher

Comment: Hi, you mentioned "changing the AppwidgetProvider caused the launcher to delete any existing widgets". Do you mean changing the code of the class that extends AppwidgetProvider?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution, but I feel sick for what it is...

After reading about how classes declared in the manifest should never change, I went and creating each class in the manifest as a class in the app, extending the corresponding class in the library. Then, I had to change every Intent to include the correct class, using forName. So, an example of this scenario is:

app package: com.sample.package

activity: MyActivity

library: com.sample.package.core

activity: MyActivity

There's a MyActivity in the app, and a MyActivity in the library. The MyActivity in the app simply extends com.sample.package.core.MyActivity.

Then, any occurrence of...

```
new Intent(context, MyActivity.class)
```

...in the library must become...

```
new Intent(context, Class.forName(context.getPackageName() + "." + MyActivity.class.getSimpleName());
```

If there's a way to do this through the manifest, please let me know!